# Need text after particular text and before other particular text

Tags: regex

I am trying parse out some text that is in an html file. The text I am trying to parse out it is the text that is always after the text developer and before the text >

So an example would be:

```
developerNeedThis1></textarea>
```

In this case I want the text: NeedThis1.

I try this:

`(?<=name=developer).*`

But this gets me:

> NeedThis1`></textarea>`

Any tips on how to also add in to get the text before

```
></textarea>
```

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Depends on what tool you're using, but here's sed:

```
sed -e 's/developer\([^>]*\)>.*/\1/'
```

Input:

```
developerNeedThis1></textarea>
```

Output:

```
NeedThis1
```

Comment: Thanks. I am using Jmeter which I believe is perl based.   I am testing in expresso and got this one to work (?<=developer).*(?=></textarea)
but I think that is for c#

Comment: @dublintech The JMeter page has examples. http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/regular_expressions.html Especially `name="file" value="(.+?)">`

Comment: link doesn't have exactly what I looking for.  your way also does not work unfortunately.  There'sa  regular expression tester in JMeter and when I test my way it works!  But, when I run the test it does not.  Very frustrating

Comment: Apache JMeter doc says: Note that (?<=regexp) - lookbehind - is not supported. Looks like I am goosed http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/regular_expressions.html